# Finding items with xpath where some elements have sub elements, but others don't

Tags: selenium, xpath

Good evening.  I have a table in Chrome for which I am trying to get all the values.  I am using Java and Selenium.  I get the headers into a List, and then peruse the rows, get each cell and get its position and get the headers and make a map.  Hope that makes sense.

I get a row at a time, and do a row.findElements(By.xpath()))....

The table would look something like the following.
I am going to use {tr}, {td}, etc., instead of <> because it gets tiring typing lt and gt.

```
 {tr}
   {td} 
     {input value='this is a cell value'} 
   {/td}
 {/tr}
 {tr}
   {td} 
     {span @class='MyClass'} This is a cell value {/span}
   {/td}
 {/tr}
 {tr}
    {td class='Want This One'} Want this value {/td}
 {/tr}
```

when there was no class='Want This One', I could do a

```
 row.findElements(By.xpath("./td//*[1][self::input[@value or @title] or self::span[@class='MyClass']")
```

but this is now not finding the {td class='Want This One'}

how can I add to the findBy a td which does not have a sub element?  Remember, it needs to be in a specific order so that it matches the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath expression:

```
//tr/td[@class='Want This One']/text()
```

Output:

> Want this value

Comment: but will that also find the other ones?  In the table, some are SPANs, some are INPUT also

Comment: @Tony - I can only work with the html you provide in the question. Try editing your question to provide examples of similar elements which you think should not be found.

Comment: Problem is it is all company confidential.  I will try to make something similar